# Jenkins Git Client Plugin fails FetchCommand execution

Tags: java, git, jenkins, groovy

For a project to improve our CI workflow we're currently implementing some kind of automatic merge behaviour for specific branches as part of our jenkins pipeline. The credentials are stored inside the jenkins credential store. Calling git commands using `sh` does not use the credential store and thus fails. Instead we tried using the [Git Client Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client). But here we come to the problem which is that the [FetchCommand](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git-client/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/FetchCommand.html)s `execute()` fails with the stacktrace below. Sadly the documentation for the git client plugin is really sparse so I tried what I could find online which is:

- manually setting the credentials using the `addDefaultCredentials` and `setCredentials` methods of the `GitClient`
- manually setting the remote URI of the target repo using the method `setRemoteUrl` of the `GitClient`

The command to fetch is set up like this:

`gitclient.fetch_().from(targetRepo, refSpecs).execute()`

targetRepo is the origin from which to fetch which is also set up as remote url

refSpecs is a list of `org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec` containing `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` which for our current test cases should be enough to check out our master.

Upon execution the exception occurs.

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2090)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:398)
Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: No such file or directory
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:1328)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1292)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:244)
Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: No such file or directory
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:255)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$2.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:628)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$2.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:630)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.mergeBranch(WorkflowScript:75)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:194)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor547.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the fact that clients require their working directory specified (i.e. they don't use the current workspace if none is supplied but rather some unknown directory)

The issue was fixed by changing the git client creation from

`Git.with(TaskListener.NULL, env.getEnvironment()).getClient()`

to

`Git.with(TaskListener.NULL, env.getEnvironment()).in(new java.io.File(pwd())).getClient()`